# Class Inheriting from Mainwindow causes "the calling thread must be sta because many UI components require this"

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on a Chat server which receives connections from multiple clients and sends/receives messages.

This is how it gets connections from the clients:

```
public void StartServer()
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 60000);
        tcpListener.Start();

        listenTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ListenLoop());
    }
    private async void ListenLoop()
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (; ; )
        {
            var socket = await _tcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync();
            if (socket == null)
                break;

            var c = new Client(socket, i);

            i++;
        }
    }////Got this code from somewhere here, not really what I want to use (discussed down)
```

This is the Client class:

```
public class Client
{
    //irrelevant stuff here//
    public Client(Socket socket, int number) 
    {
        //irrelevant stuff here//
        Thread ct = new Thread(this.run);
        ct.Start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        writer.Write("connected"); //Testing connection
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                string read = reader.ReadString();
               // Dispatcher.Invoke(new DisplayDelegate(DisplayMessage), new object[] { "[Client] : " + read });
            }////////Not working, because Client needs to inherit from MainWindow.
            catch (Exception z)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(z.Message);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so problem is, to update the UI Client class must inherit from MainWindow, but when it does, I get "the calling thread must be sta because many UI components require this" error. When it doesn't inherit it works just fine.

Another problem is, I want to use a Client[] clients array and then when a user connects, it adds him to the array so that i can individually write/read to/from specific clients.

```
while (true)
{
   try
   {
      clients[counter] = new Client(listener.AcceptSocket(), counter);
      counter ++;
      MessageBox.Show("client " + counter.ToString());
   }
   catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }

}
```

Problem here is, i get "Object refrence not set to an instance of an object" when a client connects.

Any ideas how to fix both/any of these problems?
Sorry code might be a bit messed up but I tried lots of stuff to get it working so I ended up with lots of junk in the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *“to update the UI Client class must inherit from MainWindow”* – What? Why?

Comment: A good way for the client listeners to communicate with the GUI is through a message queue. That way your single STA thread can consume incoming changes from that queue.